ML model return invalid response on Android App
I am developing an android app for predicting the placement based on 3 parameters I have developed a Flask api for the same , in postman it is return appropriate response but in the android app it is returning invalid response
Flask API
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle


model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world"

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    cgpa = float(request.form.get('cgpa'))
    iq = float(request.form.get('iq'))
    profile_score = float(request.form.get('profile_score'))

    input_query = np.array([[cgpa,iq,profile_score]])

    result = model.predict(input_query)[0]
   # print(type(result))
    return str(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Kotlin App
ApiService.kt interface
package com.example.app

import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface ApiService {
    @GET("predict")
    suspend fun fetchData(
        @Query("cgpa") cgpa: String,
        @Query("iq") iq: String,
        @Query("profile_score") profile_score: String
    ) : Response<UserData>
}

UserData.kt
package com.example.app

data class UserData(
    val cgpa: String,
    val iq: String,
    val profile_score: String
)

MainActivity.kt
package com.example.app

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.app.ui.theme.AppTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val context = getApplicationContext()
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    UserDataInput()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun UserDataInput(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        Button(onClick = {CoroutineScope(IO).launch { work()} }) {
            Text("Submit")
        }
    }
}
suspend fun work(){

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://placement-8vpr.onrender.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    val param1Value = "9.0"
    val param2Value ="120"
    val param3Value = "75"
    try {
        val response = apiService.fetchData(param1Value, param2Value, param3Value)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val data = response.body()
            Log.d("data", "${data}")
        } else {
            Log.d("data", "Invalid Response")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("exp", " Exception : ${e.message}")
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        UserDataInput()
    }
}

Debug console
2024-04-08 11:55:03.148 20764-20863 data                    com.example.app                      D  Invalid Response

Postman Response

Help appreciated!
